# What is a good book for Project Management of Software for non-programmer individuals?

Tags: software-development

I am a project manager of software developers and would like to read a book that will provide me with general information about software development. It would be good to understand what it is that I am actually managing the completion of. My developers often talk about things such as endpoints, databases, migrations, APIs, etc. These terms are above my head as I am new to IT and do not have that kind of background. Are there any recommendations of books that could help me answer some of these questions?

Comment: Please describe a concrete problem that you're facing with managing a software project, and that would probably be on-topic per our [help center](http://pm.stackexchange.com/help).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ask your developers! It's not possible to hide the fact that you are non-technical, so you might as well gain some points for trying to learn about their field. They might even have some books lying around that you can borrow.

A concrete book that I would recommend to everyone in software project management is Rapid development by Steve McConnell. It is a really good book both for general project management, and especially about the software construction process, however it won't go into details of explaining what API's and databases are.